# (MASM) - How important is restoring the stack

Tags: winapi, assembly, stack, stack-overflow, masm

I've been learning assembly recently, starting to move into some of the more complex instructions for doing things. I understand how the stack works and the size of it but how important is restoring?

Lets say we call a function that takes a 4 byte integer

```
push 0
call ...
```

Now calling this a lot would surely cause the stack to overflow? I assume this with basic knowledge but something could be handled elsewhere.

How important is popping that integer off of the stack? (Or realign the stack pointer). Is it better to do this, possibly degrading performance maybe.

I understand this could be needed in some circumstances not all.
However I noticed that calling WINAPI functions change the stack itself and not restore it, why?

Comment: WINAPI calling convention is stdcall, this means that the function called restores the stack (with a `ret <a_number_here>`). Consider what an unbalanced stack would cause in the case of a function calling another function.

Comment: Using stdcall, I assumed that it would restore itself but looking at registers before and after calling GetProcAddress it wasn't the same. I'll have a look at how I am pushing it, could be the issue really

Comment: Following the calling convention is paramount. You ask how important it is. You have to follow the calling convention. If you convention says that callee cleans up the stack, the callee does it, and the caller does not. If the convention has caller clean up then you the caller must do so. Do you know what calling convention you are using?  `stdcall` on x86 is callee clean up. `cdecl` on x86 is caller clean up.

Comment: Adjusting the stack pointer after a function call is a single-cycle operation. If you want to avoid even this, you can do like gcc does and only pop off function arguments every once in a while (e.g. at the end of a bunch of function calls). Note that doing so makes your code harder to maintain and understand.

Comment: *" but looking at registers before and after calling GetProcAddress it wasn't the same"* - what do you mean exactly? The stack (`esp/rsp` should be the same value, as **before** `push 0`, as the `GetProcAddress` should restore it (remove arguments from stack), that's how `stdcall` is defined). Values in other registers are preserved only when `stdcall` defines that for particular register, otherwise the code is free to change them (`eax, ecx, edx` are volatile, if I'm reading the wiki correctly).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question(s):

> 1. Calling a lot would cause the stack to overflow?

Not necessarily - the WINAPI calling convention has the called method pop the stack. If all the called routines had a corresponding pop, then it would not cause an overflow.

> 2. How important is popping that integer off the stack?

As it is intended for use by the called function it would be expected to be popped off somewhere - either by the code performing the call if we're using a caller cleanup calling convention, or by the routine being called if we're using a callee cleanup calling convention.

> 3. Some situations not needing it

The WINAPI has the called routine pop the stack at the end, rather than the caller. This saved memory as all the callers did not need to pop the stack. [Raymond Chen's blog has good overview of calling conventions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040102-00/?p=41213); full specifications to all of them are also [in the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

There are a lot of calling conventions, you need to follow them if you expect your code to work with other code. You can choose to 'roll your own', but you're always expected to follow some standard if you want to work with code that you didn't write.

Comment: Your point 2. is weird.  The OP said it's a function taking one integer arg, so it's a function arg.  And if you mess up the stack, the problem for callers of this function is that you return to the wrong address.  I think you're trying to say it doesn't matter *when* exactly, as long as you or the callee pop it before you return.  Anyway, see also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to calling convention / ABI docs.